# Import file into an IIFE in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, iife

Is it possible to import files into an IIFE block in Javascript just like you do with the RequireJS? I.e. is it possible to do the following:

```
define([
    '/path/to/some/file'
], function (importedFile)
{
    /* Now use imported file */

    importFile.awesomeStuff();
});
```

But with IIFE?

Comment: just define the variable `importedFile` before using IIFE.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal, but I don't want to populate the global variable.